# SignalR response read as object but should be an array

Tags: java, android, signalr

I'm receiving a response from my SignalR server (which is written in ASP.NET C#)

```
"$type":"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientHubInvocation, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core","H":"MyHub","M":"MyHubMethod","A":{"$type":"System.Object[], mscorlib","$values":[{"$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Tuple`2[[System.Int64, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Client.Common.ObjA, Client.Common]], mscorlib]], mscorlib]], mscorlib","$values":[{"$type":"System.Tuple`2[[System.Int64, mscorlib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Client.Common.ObjA, Client.Common]], mscorlib]], mscorlib"
```

using the following code:

```
proxy.on(Constants.JOURNAL_HUB_METHOD,
    new SubscriptionHandler1<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public void run(Object[] objList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SignalR reply: " + objList.length);
        }
}, Object[].class);
```

and I'm receiving the following error:

> com.android.com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Is it because the JSON response includes types? or because it's sent from C# code to java code?

Comment: It's because the "A" property is supposed to be an array but is an object. I assume it is an object because it contains types. You seem to be trying to pass some complex .NET specific structure/object. I don't know specifics of Java client but I don't see how this can work given that the types involved are .NET specific...

Comment: "A" contains two objects: "$type" and "$values" which is the array... It's a bit weird that my Javascript client can handle the .NET server without throwing errors and disconnecting, and the Java client can't.

Comment: With C#, I have `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`...

Comment: Also opened in [GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/issues/111)

Comment: It appears that the java-client project is dead... F me...